# Jest modulePathIgnorePatterns doesn't work as expected

Tags: webpack, git-submodules, jestjs

I have a submodule added to my repository, say its name is `shared-lib`. I don't want this lib to be tested by Jest runner so I added this option to Jest config in `package.json`:     `"modulePathIgnorePatterns": ["<rootDir>/shared-lib"],`
But it looks like Jest completely ignoring it. Any ideas why it could happen? Am I using it right?
and here is test script in from `package.json`
`"test": "cross-env NODE_ENV=test jest --coverage",`

Comment: have the same understanding of this option and the same problem, trying to ignore jpg, html, scss, as i use webpack and these are modules as well

Comment: I have no ideia how to use this option. I'm trying to ignore hbs files.